# Error "The extern alias 'snh' was not specified in a /reference option " in a C# test project using Microsoft Fakes

Tags: .net, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I have a C# test project that uses Microsoft fakes. 
An external library (**abc.dll**) that the project is referencing was recently updated to *.net standard 2.0*. 
After updating the **abc.dll** library reference to the latest version, the test project doesn't build any more and also doesn't generate the fake assembly for that library (**dll**).
 I see the following error in the generated **.csproj** file.

> The external alias 'snh' was not specified in a /reference option

I looked at the generated .**csproj** file and the alias snh corresponds to *System.Net.Http*.

The test project is targeting .net 4.6.1 and I'm using latest VS 2017

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This is currently an open issue with project's targeting .Net Framework 4.7.1 with a reference to netstandard libraries. It is being tracked here: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/2254.

I'll include the workaround which worked for me:
For reference, the workaround posted for the Fakes issue is to put the following in Directory.Build.targets:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'@(_NETStandardLibraryNETFrameworkLib)' != ''">
  <SnhReference Include = "@(_NETStandardLibraryNETFrameworkLib)" Condition="'%(_NETStandardLibraryNETFrameworkLib.FileName)' == 'System.Net.Http'" />

  <Reference Remove="%(SnhReference.FileName)" Condition="'@(SnhReference)' != ''"/>
  <Reference Include="%(SnhReference.FileName)" Condition="'@(SnhReference)' != ''">
    <HintPath>%(SnhReference.Identity)</HintPath>
    <Private>false</Private>
    <Aliases>snh</Aliases>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Like the OP, I am having this with a plain .NET 4.6.1 project that uses MS Fakes.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you have .NET 4.6.1, you are likely reference a .NET standard library.